# Unipotent normal subgruops of linear Lie groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear complex Lie group which is not solvable and not semisimple. let $N$ be the nilpotent radical of $G$. Does there exist a unipotent normal subgroup $U$ of $G$ which contains the last non-trivial term of the lower central series of $N$?